# How to find the row number of a specific value in Excel using vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have an open Excel file and using VB Script, I need to search only column "A" in the Excel sheet until it matches a text string.  When the script finds that match, I would like to see the row number of the cell where the match was found.
Thanks for your helps in advance!

Comment: Show the code you have so far - easier to add to that than to guess whether you really mean VBA or vbscript. As Doug mentions, they are sometimes used to mean the same thing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is VBA to find the first instance of "test2" in column A of the activesheet.  You can adjust the string and worksheet accord to your needs.  It only counts as a match if the whole cell matches, e.g., "test2222" won't match.  If you want it to, remove the , `lookat:=xlWhole` bit:

```
Sub FindFirstInstance()
Const WHAT_TO_FIND As String = "test2"
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim FoundCell As Excel.Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set FoundCell = ws.Range("A:A").Find(what:=WHAT_TO_FIND, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " found in row: " & FoundCell.Row)
Else
    MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " not found")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know.  Since your tags included `excel-vba` I gave you that code.  Sometime people use "vbscript" and "vba" interchangeably.

Comment: @buri kuri The code would require significant adapting for `vbscript`, ie to automate Excel, remove explicit dimensioning of variables, add constants for `xlWhole` etc. You need to be more specific as to what you want

Comment: Hi friends, I solved the find problem by using the solution of Doug and here is the another problem. When I try to seach "1/1/2011" from the A column, it brings "11/1/2011" row number which I don't want to match like this. How can I maintain exact matching for characters? Btw I used vbscript and here is the line --> Set FoundCell = objSheet.Range("A:A").Find("1/1/2011")

Comment: You need to get the `LookAt:=xlWhole` argument in there.  That's what @brettdj was referring to by "constants."  This is a guess, but try `objSheet.Range("A:A").Find("1/1/2011",,,1,,,,,)`.  I think this will work because `LookAt` is the 4th argument to Find and 1 is the numeric (constant) equivalent of xlWhole.

Comment: This is the answer of my question --> objSheet.Range("A:A").Find("1/1/2011",,,1)

Comment: How can I find the last instance?

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for the sample.  Below it is in VBScript

```
Dim FSO, oExcel, oData, FoundCell, WHAT_TO_FIND, File_Path

WHAT_TO_FIND = "Report Summary"
File_Path = "\\[Server]\[Drive$]\[Folder]\Data.xls"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oData = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(File_Path)

Set FoundCell = oData.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:A20000").Find(WHAT_TO_FIND)
If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " found in row: " & FoundCell.Row)
Else
  MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " not found")
End If

Set File_Path = nothing
Set WHAT_TO_FIND = nothing
Set FoundCell = nothing
Set oData = Nothing
Set oExcel = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
```

Comment: -1 for: unused FSO, () when calling MsgBox as a Sub, use Set for strings File_Path and WHAT_TO_FIND.